# Can I operate 2 electromagnetic locks using the same power supply?

Tags: power-supply, electromagnetic, dual

I'm using this power supply:
[image: My power supply]

```
Specs:
Input Voltage: AC90V-AC260V 50-60HZ
Output Voltage: DC12V
Momentary Current: 3A/5A
Persistent Current: 3.5A
```

To operate my electromagnetic lock situated on the top edge of the door.
[image]

```
Specs:
Holding force: 180kg(350lbs)
Voltage: DC 12V
Current: 380-430mA
Working temperature: -10 to 55 Celsius degree (14 to 131 Fahrenheit degree)
Humidity: 0 to 95%
Working mode: power-on to lock
```

Everything works fine except that my door is aluminum and it's flexible.
I want to connect a 2nd electromagnetic lock on the side of the door to make sure it's really locked.

Can I use the same power line connecting the first lock to also connect the 2nd lock or is it "depleting" the power supply output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two mag-locks wired in parallel will draw a max of 430 × 2 = 860 mA = 0.86 A.

Your power supply has a rating of 3 A minimum continuous.

You'll be running the power supply at 25% of rated power. It will be fine.

Comment: Isn’t it 3.5 A maximum continuous?

Comment: probably somewhere between those two extremes. The specs don't seem to be particularly accurate.

Comment: @HandyHowie, I went with the lowest number on the spec. I have no idea why it's written that way.

Comment: It was more to do with your use of the word minimum rather than maximum.

Comment: @HandyHowie, no, I considered the right term to use for a few seconds and 3 A is the lowest of the three ratings given so that's the worst case. It doesn't matter in this case as there is so much margin. Thanks though!

Comment: I understand what you were trying to say now.